# Upstairs shower not getting water

Tags: water-heater, bathroom-fixtures

I have a weird one and may not be related.  Came back from vacation and my basement was partially flooded from the Water Heater (looked like it was leaking from the bottom).  As I was cleaning it up, we noticed the 2nd story shower was leaking water (more than a drip).  I turned both valves off going to the shower till I could take a look at it.  I took out the water heater and have not replaced it yet.  I am trying to see what the deal with the shower was with just the cold water and after opening & closing the valve, no water is coming out.  Would the hot water heater have anything to do with the cold water going to the shower?  The toilet and sink both work.  Only other thing i could think of is maybe the gate valve that cuts the cold water on/off isnt working?

2nd part to this.  I had to cut the water heater to get it out.  When i cut into it, it was full.  That doesnt make sense that it was full of water when i cut it up but when i had it running, it was leaking at the bottom?  Maybe i'm losing my mind...

Comment: well, theres many things said here. The shower valve may be bad, assuming you have a single handle unit, its not unheard of that it wont operate with no pressure on the hot side. Also, unless you cut water to the tank on the inlet and the outlet, it makes sense there would be water in there. Gravity empties all the pipes above it to the lowest point. Not to mention, if the water heater gave out, and the faucet was letting water through, debris would go with it and block the valve. Pop it out and clean/replace it if needed.

Comment: Was the temperatur3e well below freezing in the house?

Comment: Water heater leaking from bottom, ok you have a problem don’t overthink it ! Replace the problem. I have seen home owners that did not have a clue waste a bunch of $ then call me and a plumber when nothing was really wrong other than a few grains of sand, or scale in a faucet, the water heater may have been bad I don’t know but after replacing a electric water heater the owner called me and a plumber in , the new heater was ok I brought it up to code electrically the plumber changed 2 o rings in a leaking sink faucet , several hundred dollars , if you have a leak fix the leak. Don’t over think

Comment: @DrMoishePippik no, the house was not below Freezing.  Outside temp was around 50-60

Comment: @EdBeal I ended up replacing the water heater already, its just not hooked up yet.  What's boggling my mind is i do not have cold water coming out of the shower upstairs.  I've opened & closed the valve's behind the shower and even taken out the Cartridge for the shower.  So i would think if i have the cold water on to the house and behind the shower, no matter what it should be coming through the shower, correct?

Comment: If your system is not finished the plumber may have closed a valve. If I pull a water heater every single valve in the house must be isolated or their might be a big leak.